# Connecting to SQL Server in a remote server from Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, windows-server

We have a Server A and a Server B.
In Server A we have our ERPs made in Access and VBA.
In Server B we have an instance of SQL Server that needs to stay in that server.
Some Access databases need to link to some tables from that SQL Server instance and I don't want the password to be stored in the MSysObjects table, so I cannot manually link the tables checking the save the connection option.

I saved the connection string in a table with password obfuscation. With that connection string I re-link the tables on startup.
The instance is accessed through it's IP, not the name of the instance. If I use the name of the instance it doesn't work.

It works for me but not for other users except one.

The SQL Server instance has been properly configured to allow remote connections, the ports have been opened and rules added to firewall. If it wasn't properly configured it wouldn't work for me and the other user, so I'm pretty confident in that. The same with the connection string and the methods to stablish the connection in Access.

What I've tried:

1. Installing the SQL Native Client 11.0.
2. Installing a full SQL Server Express.
3. Configured the SQL Browser service to star automatically instead of being disabled.

Step 1 did not work for any user. Step 2 did work for one user but not for the rest. Step 3 did not had any effect. For me I had it installed in my machine since forever, so it doesn't apply.

If I try to do the same with a SQL Server instance in our LAN it works for every user, but not when the instance is in a remote server.

Note I have limited knowledge. Maybe I say something that does not make sense.

Comment: Define "does not work". Was the server reached? was there an error with the connection? Can you ping the IP from all the PCs and get a response?

Comment: There is an error in the connection with the code 53 Could not open a connection to SQL Server. Here is the funny part: the user that can connect was granted access to the server through the needed ports and was able to ping a telnet the server. But, after installing SQL Server Express sysadmin revoke those permissions and STILL was able to connect normally to the server. I'm puzzled...

Comment: Are you using the RefreshLink method on the Access TableDef object? Access needs elevated SQL Server permissions when linking a table as it needs to query the schema. Can you turn on SQL Profiler to see what is happening when you try to reconnect?

Comment: I use RefreshLink indeed. Tomorrow I will use SQL Profiler to check it out. But if it is the case of elevated permissions how I set those permissions? I understand that we aren't talking about folder permissions or permissions to execute Access, right? Sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: As I recall, whatever user/password is used in the connection string (your obfuscated table( needs to have SQL Server permissions to query the database schema.  Ideally your connection string would use Windows AD so you're not storing passwords, so in that model, the AD user (the one logged into the workstation) would need these permissions. Are you using AD or are you embedding the password in the connection string? (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-server-security-and-linked-tables-in-access)

Comment: Yeah, AD would be great but management rejects that idea so I'm going with SQL Server authentication, so user/password... But we all share the same user/password so if permissions to schema was the case I couldn't connect either, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things:

> Installing the SQL Native Client 11.0.

Ok, then you have to re-link the tables - choose the new driver. A refresh of the linked tables is NOT sufficent. And this ALSO means that each work station ALSO now must have native 11 instlled. And if you say decide to link using native 17 (a much newer odbc driver), then AGAIN YOU must install this native driver on each work station. While you can install multiple sql drivers on each workstation, the driver you used to link the tables MUST ALSO be installed and exist on each work station.

> Installing a full SQL Server Express.

Why? What would installing a copy of sql server have to do with OTHER sql servers on other machines that you are attempting to connect to? You think installing sql server on a machine effects the sql server running say on amazon.com? So, this move makes no sense at all.

You are attempting to connect to some instance of sql server running on some other computer. Makes no sense nor will it help to install some copy of sql server that you not using, not connecting to, and that has zero to do with this issue.

> Configured the SQL Browser service to star automatically instead of being disabled.

Where? The browser service is set to run and startup on the server and SAME machine where sql server is installed and running. So, yes, without question, those two sql servers A, and B most certainly MUST have the sql browser service running. That service is what allows the client computers to connect to that running instance of sql server. In the past, older (previous) versions of sql server would allow a default connection, but now in near all cases, you MUST ensure that the sql browser service is running on that computer that also has the database you are attempting to connect to.

> it's worth to note that the instance is accessed through it's IP, not the name of the instance.

No, you likly have this incorrect. There are two part.

The server name - and then the "instance" of sql server running.

While you can swap out (not use) the server name, you STILL WILL NEED to specify the sql server instance.

So, you can use this format:

```
myservername\SQLEXPRESS
```

Or, you can replace the server with a IP address, but you STILL NEED the sql server instance. (by default, it is SQLEXPRESS - but you have to check what the instance of sql server database is).

```
192.168.1.30\SQLEXPRESS
```

So while you can use IP or server name - it is often more reliable to use the IP address, but that does NOT get you off the hook from having to specify the sql instance you connect to. Again, previous editions of sql server often allowed a "default" instance, and you did not in general have to specify the "instance", but now you do. And to be double clear, when using such a instance, that sql server needs to be running the sql browser service. (in fact, the browser service is what translates the incoming request to the given and correct instance of sql server).

> I DON'T want the password to be stored in the MSysObjects table,

You don't have to, and in fact should NOT include the uid/password in your connection string. And in fact ZERO reason exists to do so.

What you do is execute a one time logon, and THEN link the tables without UID/password. This is not only a great idea, but it also means that your uid/password is not included in the connection strings, but also means users can't get at, or even by accident see/get the uid/password.

It also means that say someone where to launch a copy of access, and import the linked tables from this applcation. When they attempt  to use the linked tables, they will NOT work.

So, then how do linked tables work without a password? (and this ALSO by the way saves you from having to re-link tables on startup!!!).

The way this works, is you in code execute a one time logon to the server on startup. That means you can either:

Prompt the user for their sql UID/password.

or

Have in code, the uid/password. (or perhaps in a text file y ou read on startup. You can thus hide, or encrypt or whatever for that uid/passwords.

Then in your startup code, you execute a one time logon. Once you done this, then all linked tables will now work - and work without having uid/password.

since you have two servers then you need to execute two logons, one for server A, and one for server B. But, once again, as long as the linked tables exist, then they will work.

Now, there are "longer" articles on how to use this logon idea, and then not have to include, or re-link your tables for the SQL uid/password.

The basic code to execute a logon is like this:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon
   
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   ' this does assume user has enough rights to query built in
   ' system tables
   
   qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 "
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True
   
   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

Keep in mind, that ONCE you acheived a legal logon, then EVEN addtional logon attempts will return true.

Not usually a big deal, but this means you supply a valid connection to above, and if it logs on and works - then now all your linked tables (without uid/password) will work.

I note the above issue that ONCE you done the logon, then all 2nd or more times running the above will work (even if bad or incorrect!!! - DO NOT forget this tip!!!).  (this can confuse the daylights out of a developer, since they execute logon, (or open a table). Then they test above routine with a BAD uid/passwords, and it works!!!

So, you have to EXIT access to clear out the password cache - no other way.

So, keep the above tips in mind.